# Printing 2D array unexpected output java

Tags: java, arrays, printing, 2d

I'm not sure if something wrong with the code because whenever I try to run it manually it works. any ideas how can I fix it?

1. this is my method

   ```
   public static int[][] mystry2d(int[][] a){
   for(int r = 0; r<a.length; r++){
   for(int c=0; c<a.length-1;c++){
   if(a[r][c+1] > a[r][c]){
    a[r][c] = a[r][c+1] ;
      }
     }
    }
     return a ;
   }
   ```
2. my printing method

   ```
          public static void printArray(int[][] arr){ 
          for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
          for(int j=0;j<arr[i].length;j++){ 
           System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
                          }
           System.out.println();
        }
    }
   ```

3.input and expected output

```
       **input:** int[][] numbers= {{3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,7},{5,6,7,8}};

       **output:** 4 5 6 6
                   5 6 7 7
                   6 7 8 8
```

4.output when running the code

```
        4 5 5 6
        5 6 6 7
        6 7 7 8
```

Comment: I'm kind of surprised that the code even build. You say that `mystry2d` should return an `int[][]`, but you don't actually return anything.

Comment: Also please read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] to show us. How are you using the functions you show? How are you initially initializing the arrays?

Comment: What's the logic behind expected output? Is it always supposed to skip the first element?

Comment: Did you debug `mystry2d`? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: public static void main(String [] args){
        int[][] numbers= {{3,4,5,6},{4,5,6,7},{5,6,7,8}};
        int[][] a = mystry2d(numbers);
               
         printArray(a);
       
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you are trying to turn this array

```
3 4 5 6
4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
```

into

```
4 5 6 6
5 6 7 7
6 7 8 8
```

so that it basically "moves" the values to the left, but only if the new values are greater than the previous ones.
However, your logic has a flaw: you use in both for loops a.length as limit, assuming the array is "square", then you correctly ignore the last column. However, in a 3x4 array, this makes the algorithm to work only on first two columns, and not on the third one!
You should look for the real length of the current line of the array in order to prevent weird bugs. Your algorithm could then become:

```
public static int[][] mystry2d(int[][] a){
 for(int r = 0; r<a.length; r++){
  for(int c=0; c<a[r].length-1;c++){
   if(a[r][c+1] > a[r][c]){
    a[r][c] = a[r][c+1] ;
   }
  }
 }
 return a ;
}
```

please, also consider caching this value so it's not re-evaluated at every iteration